# jQuery Cycle plugin animates very jerky

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-cycle

I just build a nice slider using jQuery Cycle: http://pxl.development.krout.nl/websitesnederland/

Now I'm trying to integrate that slider into our website, http://pxl.development.krout.nl/ , but I can't get it working as smooth as the example.

I tried many things, but I can't get it working without being very jerky.

Does anybody know an solution for this? That would be great!

Comment: Animates smoothly here. I can only assume the jerkiness is caused by poor browser performance when moving a large image. The quick and dirty fix to get rid of animation jerkiness is to make it faster.

Comment: Hmmm, weird. In the first example I use the same images as in the second one.
The only difference I see is that in the second example there is an complete site around the slider, wich isn't there in the first one.

Comment: @George-In FF it's good somewhat it's slow in chrome while moving from slide to slide.

Comment: I just made it a bit less jerky, but it is still far away from the first example!

Comment: have you included this for the easing thing to work?......       http://pxl.development.krout.nl/websitesnederland/js/jquery-ui-min.js

Comment: I have just exactly copied the code from the first example to the second.
Edit: yes, I did, it's in http://pxl.development.krout.nl/templates/js/library.js.
Is that script messing it up?

Answer (score 1):

if you see the working example has these includes

```
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

apart from jquery.min.js

So in your website you have changed the file names and modified the code ??

Cos in your site the includes are different files

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pxl.development.krout.nl/templates/js/library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pxl.development.krout.nl/templates/js/slider.js"></script>
```

Are you getting what I mean?

**UPDATE**

try to do this, in your slider.js, on line 17 to 25 replace with this

```
            if(bForward == true || bForward == 1) {
                $(oNext).animate({
                    'left': $(window).width()+'px'
                });
            } else {
                $(oNext).animate({
                    'left': '-'+$(window).width()+'px'
                });
            }
```

Comment: I understand yes.I put al the code from jquery-ui-min.js, jquery.cycle.all.min.js into one file: library.js

Comment: I put the includes just like the first example, but it doesn't take effect :-(

Comment: could you resize the images to fit the height 533px and width 1230px.... cos the actual images are around 2000px high and 990px wide this should do the trick

Comment: 533px height and 1230px width is your viewport minus the menu-height and the height of the white bar ('Wat heb jij te vertellen'), witch has an height of 150px.
On big screens (very common in the advertising industry) you also want to have a nice picture. I'm now trying to compress the images a bit with JPEG.